# How to count equal, adjacent elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

Lets say I have a `vector<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 }` and I'd like to convert this into a `vector<std::pair<int, int>> { {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {1, 2} }` of 'adjacent element counts':

I'd probably iterate over the vector with a flag indicating the start of a new 'adjacency set' and a counter which counts the number of consecutive elements. I was just wondering if there isn't already a more abstract and elegant solution in the STL as this seems like a very common use-case. Algorithms like unique, adjacent_find or equal_range seem pretty close to what I'm looking for but just not quite the right thing and probably no gain to implementing it from scratch myself.

Comment: "I was just wondering if there isn't already a more abstract and elegant solution in the STL as this seems like a very common use-case" For a vector? Maybe for a map, and still "common" is a stretch.

Comment: There is no-builtin algorithm in the C++ library that does anything like this. It's up to you to implement it. And sounds like you already have a good grasp on the algorithm, so it makes no sense to wait for an answer that won't be coming, from someone on the intertubes.

Comment: What are adjacent elements in a vector? There are at least two interpretations. What hinders you to simply interate through the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eric Niebler's `range` library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which, [AFAIU is in the process of becoming part of the standard library](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html), has a `group_by` which is very similar to [Python's `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and groups consecutive equivalent elements, just as you need.

To group your vector, you'd start with

```
const vector<int> l{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 };
auto x = l | view::group_by(std::equal_to<int>());
```

which means that `x` is a view where adjacent integers belong to a group, if the integers are equal.

Now to iterate, and say, print each consecutive group and its size, you could do the following (I'm sure you can do it better than the following, but this is the limit of my use of this library):

```
for (auto i = x.begin();i != x.end(); ++i) 
    cout <<  *((*i).begin()) << " " << to_vector(*i).size() << endl;
```

---

**Example**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    const std::vector<int> l{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 };
    auto x = l | ranges::view::group_by(std::equal_to<int>());

    for (auto i = x.begin();i != x.end(); ++i) 
        std::cout <<  *((*i).begin()) << " " << ranges::to_vector(*i).size() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints out

```
$ ./a.out 
1 2
2 1
3 3
1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

From an algorithmic point of view the closest thing is [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) I would say. I don't think there is a ready made algorithm to do that, but the code should be trivial:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> out; 
for (int i: in)
{
     if (out.empty() || out.back().first != i)
     {
         out.emplace_back(i, 1);
     }
     else
     {
         ++out.back().second;
     }
}
```

[Live-example.](http://ideone.com/RwmfCl)

Comment: I find this implementation very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

With `std`, you may do:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::pair<T, std::size_t>>
adjacent_count(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<T, std::size_t>> res;

    for (auto it = v.begin(), e = v.end(); it != e; /*Empty*/) {
        auto it2 = std::adjacent_find(it, e, std::not_equal_to<>{});
        if (it2 != e) {
            ++it2;
        }
        res.emplace_back(*it, std::distance(it, it2));
        it = it2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/c0lRZD)

or

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::pair<T, std::size_t>>
adjacent_count(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<T, std::size_t>> res;

    for (auto it = v.begin(), e = v.end(); it != e; /*Empty*/) {
        const auto it2 = std::find_if(it, e, [&](const auto&x) { return x != *it; });
        res.emplace_back(*it, std::distance(it, it2));
        it = it2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/2H3I3X)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such C++ library that will automatically do what you are asking.
Anyway, it is very simple to implement this though. Here is one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void count_equal_elements(vector<int>& vec, vector<pair<int,int> >& result){
    if (vec.empty())
        return;
    int curr = vec[0];
    int count = 1;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin()+1; it != vec.end(); ++it){
        if (curr == *it){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            result.push_back(make_pair(curr,count));
            curr = *it;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    result.push_back(make_pair(curr,count));
}
```

See it in [ideone](https://ideone.com/UQmw0A).